# C#: How can I use the content of a string variable to call a method with the same name?

Tags: c#

Lots of answers on SO, but none for C# that I could see.

My current method looks like this:

```
    private static decimal SelectOperation(decimal numDisplay, decimal numInput, string operation)
    {
        switch (operation)
        {
            case "":
                return (numInput == 0) ? numDisplay : numInput;
            case "Addition":
                return Operations.Addition(numDisplay, numInput);
            case "Subtraction":
                return Operations.Subtraction(numDisplay, numInput);
            case "Multiplication":
                return Operations.Multiplication(numDisplay, numInput);
            case "Division":
                return Operations.Division(numDisplay, numInput);
            case "Power":
                return Operations.Power(numDisplay, numInput);
            case "Modulus":
                return OperationsLibrary.Operations.Modulus(numDisplay, numInput);
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException(operation);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to simplify this by using the *operation* string as part of the method call. Doing something like this:

```
    private static decimal SelectOperation(decimal numDisplay, decimal numInput, string operation)
    {
        if (operation == "") return (numInput == 0) ? numDisplay : numInput;

        try
        {
             return System.CallMethod($"Operations.{operation}(numDisplay, numInput)");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw NotImplementedException(operation);
        }
    }
```

Does C# have a method like *System.CallMethod()* which I just made up? Or is there another way to simplify my code? Thanks!

Comment: Is this real code or just to for asking this question? I ask because calling `SelectOperation` and passing a `string` to it as the operation name is not very user-friendly. Why not allow the user to call `Operations.<Method Name>` directly?

Comment: @CodingYoshi This code is behind the scenes far away from any user. They click buttons on my GUI. When any operation button is pressed, the XAML ShellView calls a command in the ShellViewModel and passes a string such as "addition", depending on the button. That command then calls a method in my Logic layer which is in a separate project. I've done it this way because I was told it was best to separate the UI and business layers as much as possible. This way, the ShellView only knows about one method rather than seven or eight. Is that an acceptable way to do things?

Comment: Well the ShellView knows about the one method but also needs to know the exact name of the other methods but only by string. The problem with this approach is you get no compiler support. If you put "Adition" (one less d), it will still pass compilation but crash at runtime. Thus to answer your question, I don't think it is an ideal way to do it; at least I would not do it that way. Technically, if it was a huge application with over 1000 methods, you can abstract them all using your approach so the ShellView only knows one operation. But it actually knows more. No compiler support is bad.

Comment: Exactly, I'd like to practise techniques that can be scaled for large applications. I think having a method in the ViewModel for each individual button in the View would be less maintainable than having one method handle all the buttons. I didn't think about the fact that passing strings would reduce compiler support. If you can suggest a way to increase compiler support without bloating the ViewModel, that would be fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: Like I said, passing strings doesn't mean the ShellView is not coupled to the business layer. It is coupled but it is only coupled through strings. In addition to being coupled, you also don't have compiler support. When I used that example about 1000 methods, I meant that is not something one should do; at least I would not.

Comment: If you can suggest a preferred way, that would be great.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Call the method directly. If you change your method name, compilation will fail. Right now if you change the method name, compilation will not fair (bad). 2) Create an interface and use the interface in the shellview. If you change the implementation, you will only need to change the part when you `new` up the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use reflection, as mentioned by another answer, and while that fits your question exactly, it is highly unlikely that the issue you've shown would ever be solved with reflection in any production application - because reflection is *very expensive*, and *does not provide any type safety* - notice the arguments passed into the function via reflective `method.Invoke` call are an `object[]` - so hopefully they're correct, but you'll only know at runtime.

A far better solution in a simple case like yours is a `Dictionary<string, Func<TNum1, TNum2, TResult>>`, which can be configured like so:

```cs
static Dictionary<string, Func<decimal, decimal, decimal>> mathOperations =
    new Dictionary<string, Func<decimal, decimal, decimal>>()
    {
        ["Addition"] = (a, b) => a + b,
        ["Subtraction"] = (a, b) => a - b,
        ["Multiplication"] = (a, b) => a * b,
        ["Division"] = (a, b) => a / b,
        ["Power"] = (a, b) => (decimal)Math.Pow((double)a, (double)b),
        ["Modulus"] = (a, b) => a % b
    };

private static decimal SelectOperation(decimal a, decimal b, string operation)
{
    if (!mathOperations.TryGetValue(operation, out var mathFunc)) throw new NotImplementedException();
    return mathFunc(a, b);
}
```

Now, `string` comparisons and hashing are also somewhat costly, so it would be *even better* if you can introduce an `enum` that defines the math operations, and map the `enum` members to the `Func`s in the `Dictionary`; but the idea is the same.

Comment: @downvoter, would you please mind explaining the reason for downvoting my answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can use reflection to do it

```
MethodInfo method = service.GetType().GetMethod(serviceAction);
object result = method.Invoke(service, new object[] { request });
return (R) result;
```

Comment: This is correct, however there are some hude trade offs around correctness and performance with reflection. It would be good to mention them too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll use a dictionary to solve this particular problem, but I will look up reflection.